# pass value from span tag to input tag

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a counter in `span tag`s, when I press `Start` the timer starts counting and when pressing `Pause` it is stopped. Now the question is, How do I pass the value from the counter to `input tag` when `Pause` clicked?

```
<span id="min">00</span>:<span id="sec">00</span>

<input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start">
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">
```

Script

```
<script>
        const Clock = {
            totalSeconds: 0,
            start: function () {
                if (!this.interval) {
                    const self = this;

                    function pad(val) {
                        return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
                    }

                    this.interval = setInterval(function () {
                        self.totalSeconds += 1;

                        document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60));
                        document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60));
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },

            pause: function () {
                clearInterval(this.interval);
                delete this.interval;
            },

        };

        document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click", function () { Clock.start(); });
document.getElementById("pauseButton").addEventListener("click", function () { Clock.pause(); });


    </script>
```

Here it is as a runnable snippet:

```js
const Clock = {
  totalSeconds: 0,
  start: function() {
    if (!this.interval) {
      const self = this;

      function pad(val) {
        return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
      }

      this.interval = setInterval(function() {
        self.totalSeconds += 1;

        document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60));
        document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60));
      }, 1000);
    }
  },

  pause: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    delete this.interval;
  },

};

document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  Clock.start();
});
document.getElementById("pauseButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  Clock.pause();
});
```

```html
<span id="min">00</span>:<span id="sec">00</span>

<input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start">
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">
```

Comment: to which input tag, you want to add to a third input tag? you have 2 input button tags

Comment: You track the time in code already so use that to populate the input just like you do with the time display.

Comment: the idea is , when clicked `Pause` the `span min` and `span sec` join together as 00.00 and pass to new hidden `input tag`

Comment: @Ouroborus, just getting to java script so some example will help more :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I adjustment your script with template string javascript created with a variable time and improvement your double tags for a tag with id "time-span" and "time-input" both with return variable time
Also in Clock inserted pad function property and acess inside start with self variable

See this code and working

### Update

Improvement with new input time last show time after pause.

```js
const Clock = {
  totalSeconds: 0,
  time: null,
  pad: function (val) {
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
  },
  start: function () {
    const self = this;

    if (!self.interval) {
      self.interval = setInterval(function () {
        self.totalSeconds += 1;
        let min = self.pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60));
        let sec = self.pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60));

        self.time = `${min}:${sec}`;
        document.getElementById("time-span").innerHTML = self.time;
        document.getElementById("time-input").value = self.time;
      }, 1000);
    }
  },
  createInputResult: function () {
    const self = this;
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    let line = document.createElement('hr');

    input.id = 'time-result';
    input.type = 'text';
    input.value = self.time;    
    document.getElementById("pauseButton").insertAdjacentElement('afterend', input);
    document.getElementById("pauseButton").insertAdjacentElement('afterend', line);
  },
  pause: function () {
    const self = this;
    clearInterval(self.interval);
    delete self.interval;
    self.createInputResult();
  },
};

document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click", () => Clock.start() );
document.getElementById("pauseButton").addEventListener("click", () => Clock.pause() );
```

```html
<!-- Times -->
<span id="time-span">00:00</span>
<input id="time-input" type="text" value="00:00">

<!-- Controls -->
<input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start">
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">
```

Comment: Thanks @mar24n i improvement with new tag show last time after button pause.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const Clock = {
  totalSeconds: 0,
  start: function() {
    if (!this.interval) {
      const self = this;

      function pad(val) {
        return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
      }

      this.interval = setInterval(function() {
        self.totalSeconds += 1;

        document.getElementById("min").innerHTML = pad(Math.floor(self.totalSeconds / 60 % 60));
        document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML = pad(parseInt(self.totalSeconds % 60));
      }, 1000);
    }
  },

  pause: function() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    var text = document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML
    
    
    document.getElementById('startButton').value=text;
    delete this.interval;
  },

};

document.getElementById("startButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  Clock.start();
});
document.getElementById("pauseButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
  Clock.pause();
});
```

```html
<span id="min">00</span>:<span id="sec">00</span>

<input id="startButton" type="button" value="Start">
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for , thank you

Comment: Since you're not getting (and don't want) any markup from within the "sec" span, `.innerText` is a better choice. Only use `.innerHTML` when you want to get or modify structure.